# How to take a list of Numbers that contain decimals and turn it into a list of Whole Numbers only. (Excel 2019 answer only)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

There was a similar question posted about this that works well with Office 365. However, an answer that works for Excel 2019 is gladly appreciated as well as a formula that work regardless if there is other calculations in the workbook.

For example if I have a list of number in excel that contain whole numbers and numbers with decimals such as this image here:

[image: 1]

I would like to create a table that automatically disregards the numbers with decimals and displays a list with whole numbers only for example:

[image: 2]

The current formula that works well in office 365 is
`=FILTER(selected_list),INT(Selected_list)=Selected_list)` where `selected_list` is the name range for the list that contains both the whole numbers and decimals. An office 2019 solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Gave you an answer that uses functions not limited to 365. Not doing it again.

Comment: On top of that there's already an office 2019 solution provided there.

Answer (score 1):

If every element of the array is a number, you can search for a decimal in each element, and then only return the element if it doesn't contain one.

For example: `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(".", I2)>0, ""),I2)`

[image]

From there you can sort the resultant array after copying and pasting values over if that is the sort of thing you want.